# How to Select Specific List Items in Dynamic Bootstrap navbar menu for WordPress

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a dynamic bootstrap navbar menu for WordPress. To see the menu design, please visit this link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/211935016/images/created_menu.jpg

But there are some things that still need to be done. The top nag “Special Promotions” and “Board Certified” need to have that box around them so they stand out. To see the design, please visit this link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/211935016/images/original_menu.jpg

Here is the html code:

```
<!-- Menu's Code for Twitter Bootstrap -->
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse container mainmenu" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"   data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Naavigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="" >Navigation</a>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <?php

    $args = array(
            'theme_location' => 'top-bar',
            'depth'          => 2,
            'container'      => false,
            'menu_class'     => 'nav navbar-nav',
            'walker'         => new Bootstrap_Walker_Nav_Menu()
    );
    wp_nav_menu($args);

    ?>
 </div>
 </div>
 <!-- Menu's Code for Twitter Bootstrap -->
```

Here is the css code:

```
.mainmenu {background:#F2F0F1;border:none;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {color: #101010;}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:hover {color: #101010;}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {border-color: #333333;background:#333333;}
.navbar-collapse {padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;}
.navbar-brand {display:none;}
.mainmenu ul.navbar-nav {margin-left: -10px;}
.mainmenu ul.navbar-nav li {margin-top: 12px;margin-left: 10px;}
.mainmenu ul.navbar-nav li a {color:#101010;padding: 5px 2px;font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-size:18px;}
.mainmenu ul.navbar-nav li a:hover {color:#fff;background:#13B4E3;}
```

And I use this code: http: // pastebin dot com/S0UCDUYi in functions.php file to activate Bootstrap navbar menu for WordPress.

Can anybody help me to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to add a new class for those two menu items on the Wordpress | Appearance | Menus page.

To make sure you can view menu CSS classes:

- Go the the menu editing page
- Click Screen Options at the top right of the screen
- Under 'Show advanced menu properties' click 'CSS Classes'

Now in the entries for those two pages in the menu ( “Special Promotions” and “Board Certified” ) you can add a new class such as 'highlight'.

Then add in the css for that new class:

```
.highlight { background: blue ... }
```

Comment: Hi @manishie, Thanks for your answer. You are right. But need some little JavaScript to activate it such as 
`<script type="text/javascript">
$('.mainmenu ul.navbar-nav').click(function() {
$('.highlight').toggleClass('active');
});
</script>`